# NullpointerException after OnCreate-Method with Spinner/String Array

Tags: android

after my main activity calls the following activity my app crashes with a nullpointer exception (seen in LogCat).
After debugging and monitoring my variables i can't figure out where the problem is.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
private Spinner pay_spend;
private Spinner pay;
private Spinner person;
private EditText edit_pay;
private boolean initCall;

private OnItemSelectedListener itemSelected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_einbezahlen);

    pay_spend = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_bezahlen_spende);
    pay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_bezahlen);
    person = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_person);
    edit_pay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_field_einzahlen);
    pay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    edit_pay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    this.initOnItemSelectedListener();
    pay_spend.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelected);
}

private void initOnItemSelectedListener() {
    itemSelected = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if(initCall) {
                initCall = false;
            } else {
                if(position == 0) {
                    edit_pay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    pay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    pay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    edit_pay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }               
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            pay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            edit_pay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };
}
```

At every breakpoint my variables are set and correct, the string-arrays with the entries for the spinners are set and have the correct amount of values (same for the int-array)

XML for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_bezahlen_spende"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner_person"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_person"
    android:entries="@array/bezSpende"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_person"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:entries="@array/personen"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_bezahlen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner_bezahlen_spende"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_bezahlen_spende"
    android:entries="@array/kosten"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_einzahlen_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_rueckmeldung"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_einzahlen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_rueckmeldung"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_einzahlen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_field_einzahlen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="@string/txt_btn_einzahlen" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/id_field_einzahlen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_bezahlen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:labelFor="@+id/id_field_einzahlen"
    android:text="@string/txt_betrag_eingeben" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I just started programming with Android SDK thats why nearly all the XML code was generated with the graphical tool given by eclipse

LogCat:

```
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704): Process: de.storno.wortspielkasse, PID:5704
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:505)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:722)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:458)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5257)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5257)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5257)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2429)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16987)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1157)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1368)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5749)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:738)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
10-16 06:31:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(5704):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
```

Also when the ZygoteInit$Method... is called an error with "Source not found." is displayed

I've searched the web for nearly 4h now and havn't found ANY solution for my problem.
Hope you can give me any advice or hints to get rid of this problem

Big Thanks in advance

---

Edit:
I just found out i got some problems with the int-array. Its not initialized correctly (all values are null), but with the right amount of entries.

```
<integer-array name="kosten">
    <item >10</item>
    <item >20</item>
    <item >30</item>
    <item >40</item>
    <item >50</item>
    <item >60</item>
    <item >70</item>
    <item >80</item>
    <item >90</item>
    <item >100</item>
</integer-array>
```

i'm curretly looking for a solution

Comment: are you sure about this `tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item" />`?

Comment: Look at this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html - It's 3 more lines in java and 2 lines less in xml,  per each Spinner. Total: 1 more line per Spinner. But this one **works**.

Comment: Maybe you can try to add the spinner items and the adapter before set the listener, programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For spinner `entries`, use a `string-array` instead of `integer-array`.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement the itemSelect OnItemSelectedListener on the onCreate() method, I have had problems with that before.

Comment: moved it into the onCreate() method, no effects and the same exception